# AttributeError: 'MLPClassifier' object has no attribute 'best_loss_'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, attributeerror, mlp

I was experimenting with the warm_start parameter in scikit-learn's MLPClassifier. However, I received an error while running the following code.

```
    clf = MLPClassifier(solver='adam',
                        hidden_layer_sizes=(128, 128),
                        activation='relu',
                        max_iter = 3,
                        verbose=True,
                        tol= 1e-100,
                        n_iter_no_change=10,
                        early_stopping=True,
                        warm_start=True)

    clf.fit(df_feat, df_label)
    clf.fit(df_feat, df_label)
```

Below is my output and error message. The first clf.fit() was able to run to completion, but the second clf.fit() produced an error message after 1 iteration.

```
Iteration 1, loss = 1.84596208
Validation score: 0.610841
Iteration 2, loss = 1.04435735
Validation score: 0.731758
Iteration 3, loss = 0.84135025
Validation score: 0.760945
C:\Users\LHongRu1\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\_multilayer_perceptron.py:571: ConvergenceWarning: Stochastic Optimizer: Maximum iterations (3) reached and th
e optimization hasn't converged yet.
  % self.max_iter, ConvergenceWarning)
Iteration 4, loss = 0.77392135
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_3(to_experiment).py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
  File "train_3(to_experiment).py", line 62, in main
    clf.fit(df_feat, df_label)
  File "C:\Users\LHongRu1\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\_multilayer_perceptron.py", line 995, in fit
    hasattr(self, "classes_")))
  File "C:\Users\LHongRu1\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\_multilayer_perceptron.py", line 370, in _fit
    intercept_grads, layer_units, incremental)
  File "C:\Users\LHongRu1\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\_multilayer_perceptron.py", line 540, in _fit_stochastic
    self._update_no_improvement_count(early_stopping, X_val, y_val)
  File "C:\Users\LHongRu1\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\_multilayer_perceptron.py", line 604, in _update_no_improvement_count
    if self.loss_curve_[-1] > self.best_loss_ - self.tol:
AttributeError: 'MLPClassifier' object has no attribute 'best_loss_'
```

If I change to `warm_start = False`, both clf.fit() are able to run to completion.

Comment: You mean, the first `clf.fit` is run through completion (3 iterations) with the `ConvergenceWarning`, and the second `clf.fit` produces the error?

Comment: @desertnaut Yes. I have edited the post for clarity.

Comment: did you ever find a solution? I have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Try `early_stopping=False`, it works for me. to solve the problem.